# Deploying a solidity smart contract to polygon matic

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, polygon

I'm new to blockchain development and smart contracts. I've learned to create smart contracts with Solidity and deploy them on the Ethereum network. I'm planning to transition to polygon because of ETH gas fees. I'm not able to adequately test my code on mainnet because of very high gas fees. I've read that polygon smart contracts are also developed in Solidity. I've tried searching "Difference between ETH and Polygon smart contracts" but didn't find any good resource that explains this well.

can someone briefly explain the difference between the two or share any resource link? can I deploy my smart contract that is deployed on ETH to polygon? Is there anything I need to change?

Comment: You just connect to polygon node instead of ethereum node.. basically that is all.. everything still the same. Some additional things -> the deployer account should have matic on the polygon network. And if your contract interacting with other contracts then you need to find if those contract exists on the polygon network and find the addresses of those contracts on polygon and change them

Comment: Polygon mainnet is the new testnet: https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1452013304084316167

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Difference between ETH and Polygon smart contracts

There is none. Polygon runs barely modified GoEthereum, same as Ethereum mainnet, which runs EVM virtual machine.

Your smart contracts are deployable across all EVM compatible chains, like Polygon, Avalanche, Binance Smart Chain, Fanton, Telos EVM and couple of other chains.

Comment: But some values in Solidity are expressed as "ether". This would have to change, no? Is there an equivalent unit, like "matic"?

Comment: That's only because Polygon developers are so lazy that they do not bother to change ether. See also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055445/what-is-difference-between-binance-smart-chain-and-ethereum-network/70103844#70103844